# Coaxing DSolve to produce an implicit solution

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I try to solve the differential equation

```
  DSolve[{3*y[x] + 2*x*y[x]^2 + (2*x + 3*x^2*y[x])*y'[x] == 0, y[1] == 1/2}, y[x], x]
```

This produces some error messages as

> DSolve::bvnul: For some branches of the general solution, the given
>   boundary conditions lead to an empty solution.

It also produces:

$$y(x)\to \text{Root}\left[-8 \text{$\#$1}^5+\frac{40 \text{$\#$1}^4}{x}-\frac{80 \text{$\#$1}^3}{x^2}+\text{$\#$1}^2 \left(\frac{80}{x^3}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)-\frac{40 \text{$\#$1}}{x^4}+\frac{8}{x^5}\&,1\right]$$

I know this DEQ is solvable because I did it by hand (see implicit solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140226/exact-de-y2xy3dxx3xy2dy-0/2140279#2140279) and verified it using [*WA*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(2xy%5E2%2B3y)%2B(3x%5E2y%2B2x)y%27+%3D0,+y(1)+%3D+1%2F2).

Is there any way to coax *Mathematica* to produce that result using `DSolve` in spite of that nasty IC?

I am using Windows 7, MMA version $11.0.1.0$.

Comment: The solution shown on WA has `y(x)` in three of the `log` terms. Are you sure there is a solution for this ODE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Update

Seems that `DSolve` is further improved after *v11.0*, the simplification below is no longer needed now. See [Carl's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174467/1871) for more details.

---

## Original Answer

This is another improvement of `DSolve` after *v9*. In *v9* `DSolve` will give the implicit form as the output. Still, it's possible to dig out the implicit solution in *v11*:

```
mid = Trace[
    DSolve[{3 y[x] + 2 x y[x]^2 + (2 x + 3 x^2 y[x]) y'[x] == 0, y[1] == 1/2}, y[x], x], 
    Solve[_, y[x]], TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union
```

It's not hard to find the second to last element of `mid` is the general implicit solution:

```
mid[[-2]]

(*
HoldForm[Solve[45 (3 C[1] + 
     28 RootSum[-28 + 57 7^(1/3) #1 - 28 #1^3 &, 
       Log[-#1 + (-16 + 21 x y[x])/(2 7^(1/3) (2 + 3 x y[x]))]/(19 7^(1/3) - 
           28 #1^2) &]) == 2 7^(2/3) Log[x], y[x]]]
 *)
```

Let's simplify it a bit:

```
generaleq = mid[[-2]][[1, 1]] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify
(* 135 C[1] == 
 2 7^(2/3) (Log[3125/108] + Log[x] + 3 Log[1/(-2 - 3 x y[x])] + 
    2 Log[(x y[x])/(2 + 3 x y[x])] - 5 Log[(-1 + x y[x])/(2 + 3 x y[x])]) *)
```

And eliminate `C[1]` with the constraint `y[1] == 1/2`:

```
const = Solve[generaleq /. y[x] -> 1/2 /. x -> 1, C[1]][[1]];
eq = generaleq /. const // Simplify
(* -2 I π + Log[8] + 5 Log[(-1 + x y[x])/(2 + 3 x y[x])] == 
   Log[x] + 3 Log[1/(-2 - 3 x y[x])] + 2 Log[(x y[x])/(2 + 3 x y[x])] *)
```

OK, we find the implicit solution.

BTW, despite the warning, the solution given by `DSolve` in *v11* is correct:

```
Select[Solve[eq, y[x]], y[x] == 1/2 /. # /. x -> 1 &]
(* {{y[x] -> Root[
      8/x^5 - (40 #1)/x^4 + (80/x^3 - 1/x^2) #1^2 - (80 #1^3)/x^2 + (40 #1^4)/x - 8 #1^5&,
        1]}} *)
```

Comment: Improvement? Seems like this is a regression. :-) Even in WA, they are able to produce a result and it looks like V9 did that. I am going to have start keeping those older versions around. Thanks!

Comment: @moo A regression for people who just want the implicit solution :) . It would be good if an option or so can be added for `DSolve` to switch the behavior.

Comment: That is an excellent idea or maybe it gives the implicit solution without trying to figure out the constant, but tells you that the result branches. Thanks.

Comment: I fail to understand one thing, why we need to do so much to get the same thing, which we can get directly from `DSolve`?

Comment: @mmm Because OP wants the implicit solution expressed as a equation involving `Log`. (See the edit of the question. )

Comment: @xzczd Oh... I didn't saw that. These OPs are keep changing the questions. It's hard to follow. It seems that my response was just a waste of time.

Comment: @mmm There's no doubt that your response helps :) , it tells us that, though some warning is generated when calculating, the answer outputed by _Mathematica_ is probably correct, given _Maple_ gives the same solution. Actually it's after reading your answer that I noticed I have misundersood the question (I thought OP thinks `DSolve` missed a solution or so).

Comment: Hi,I used this code to solve the implicit function solution of a ODE, but it was unsuccessful:  Clear[eqn, eq, sol, x, y];
eq = y'[x] == 1/(x - y[x]) + 1;
mid = Trace[DSolve[eq, y[x], x], Solve[_, y[x]], 
     TraceInternal -> True] // Flatten // Union;
generaleq = mid[[-2]][[1, 1]] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify

Comment: @lotus2019 Seems that `DSolve` has used a different method when solving your equation and `Solve` is not called as the last step. Well, but why do you need implicit solution in this case? The explicit solution is simple.

Comment: @xzczd Thank you.  The explicit solution is solution on complex fields: {{y[x] -> x - I*Sqrt[-x^2 - 2*(-x - x^2/2) - C[1]]}, {y[x] ->  x + I*Sqrt[-x^2 - 2*(-x - x^2/2) - C[1]]}}. However, the implicit solution is simple: (x-y[x])^2+2x==C.

Comment: @lotus2019 You can `Solve` for it if you like. Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183826/1871

Answer (score 8):

Here is a refinement of @xzczd's [`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace) idea (originally posted as an answer to question [(174383)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/174383/45431)):

```
Quiet @ Trace[
    DSolve[{3*y[x]+2*x*y[x]^2+(2*x+3*x^2*y[x])*y'[x]==0,y[1]==1/2},y[x],x],
    Solve[e_, y[x]] -> (eqn = e),
    TraceInternal->True
];
eqn
```

> 3 Log[x] + 2 Log[y[x]] - 5 Log[1 - x y[x]] == C[1]

This produces the implicit equation that the OP referenced in his linked question.

Comment: Very clean (+1).

Comment: Seems that `DSolve` is further improved after my answer is posted. I vaguely remembered that in I only found the complicated equation involving `RootSum` in _2017.2.12_. (Probably in _v11.0_? )

Comment: Hi, I used this code to solve the implicit function solution of a ODE, but it was unsuccessful. Clear[eqn, eq, sol, x, y]; eq = y'[x] == 1/(x - y[x]) + 1; Quiet@
 Trace[DSolve[eq, y[x], x], Solve[e_, y[x]] -> (eqn = e), 
  TraceInternal -> True];
eqn

Answer (score 3):

**Maple**

I tried the same ode in Maple and it also produces the solution in terms of `RootOf`, the maple routine "a placeholder for representing all the roots of an equation in one variable". But there is also an option which is self explanatory `remove_RootOf`.

Thus, maple was able to produce an implicit solution to the problem in a much more simplified form.

```
restart:with(plots):
ode:=3*y(x) + 2*x*y(x)^2 + (2*x + 3*x^2*y(x))*diff(y(x),x)= 0;
sol:=dsolve({ode,y(1)=1/2});
```

[image]

Now to get rid of the `RootOf` we need to load the package `DEtools` first,

```
DEtools:-remove_RootOf(sol);
```

[image]

Now comparing the two different forms of the same solution,

```
p1:=plot(rhs(sol),x=1..10,color=green,axes=boxed,linestyle=3):
p2:=implicitplot(-8+8*(y)^5*x^5-40*(y)^4*x^4+80*(y)^3*x^3+(x-80)*(y)^2*x^2+40*y*x=0,x=1..10,y=0..1,color=red,axes=boxed,linestyle=1):
display({p1,p2});
```

[image]

***Mathematica***

You can get the desired result in *MMA* too.

[image]

Now plugin `y[x]` for `#1`
[image]

> -(8/x) + 40 y[x] - 80 x y[x]^2 + x^2 y[x]^2 + 80 x^2 y[x]^3 - 
>     40 x^3 y[x]^4 + 8 x^4 y[x]^5 == 0

Comment: Try in Maple `dsolve({ode, y(1) = 1/2}, implicit)` no need  remove `RootOf` or with Integrals: `dsolve({ode, y(1) = 1/2}, useInt, implicit)`