# How to stop DSolve from solving equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

I'm tring to solve this ODE, `DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + (x/y[x])^2] - x/y[x], y[x], {x}]`. Mathematica gives this as the result:

[image]

I don't want Mathematica to solve the final (implicit) equation. I know that this code

```
Block[{Integrate = Inactive@Integrate}, 
 DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + (x/y[x])^2] - x/y[x], y[x], {x}]]
```

can stop `DSolve` from integrating, so I tried this

```
Block[{Solve = Inactive@Solve}, 
 DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + (x/y[x])^2] - x/y[x], y[x], {x}]]
```

but it didn't work:

[image]

So how should I proceed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that `Solve` will be called during the `DSolve` calculation, so if you stop `Solve`, the `DSolve` doesn't work as well.

To avoid that, we can think in another way. Do not **stop** `Solve`, but **store** the equations whenever `Solve` is called. The last stored equations is what you need.

Here is a sample code, the usage of `Block` comes from [What are some advanced uses for Block?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11579/what-are-some-advanced-uses-for-block/11585#11585)

```
Unprotect[Solve];
Solve[args___ /; ! TrueQ[inF]] := Block[{inF = True}, Sow[args]; Solve[args]];
Protect[Solve];

Reap[DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + (x/y[x])^2] - x/y[x], y[x], {x}]][[2, -1]]

(*{Log[1 - Sqrt[1 + y[x]^2/x^2]] == C[1] - Log[x]}*)
```

Comment: Nice idea (+1).

Answer (score 5):

I do not know why the approach taken in the question does not work, because it depends on the inner workings of `DSolve`.  However, this may provide the desired result.

```
Quiet@Block[{Integrate = Inactive@Integrate}, 
    DSolve[y'[x] == Sqrt[1 + (x/y[x])^2] - x/y[x], y[x], {x}]];
Activate[%[[1]] /. y[x] -> z[x] x] /. z[x] -> y[x]/x

(* -ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 + y[x]^2/x^2]] + 1/2 Log[-(y[x]^2/x^2)] == C[1] - Log[x] *)
```