# How to obtain the solution of an ODE in implicit form?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to get the general solution of a first-order ODE in implicit form.
It should be something like this:

1. With input `y'[x] == 1`, the desired output is `C[1]->y[x] - x`.
2. With input `y'[x] == 1/y[x]^2` (nonlinear ODE), the desired output is `C[1]->y[x]^3/3 - x`

`DSolve` tries to evaluate the explicit form of `y[x]` by default. Is it possible to keep the implicit solution?

I tried explicit equation integration using `Integrate` and tracing (`Trace` with `TraceInternal -> True`). Neither helped me with this problem.

Comment: Strongly related, if not duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137598/1871

Comment: But this seems not to work correctly. `Quiet@Trace[DSolve[y'[x] == 1, y[x], x], Solve[e_, y[x]] -> (eqn = e),
    TraceInternal -> True];
eqn` returns `-1 + y[x] == 0` with no integration constant

Comment: Yes, and that's the reason I didn't vote for close as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for the two examples in the OP:

```
eq = y'[x] == 1; (* try also eq = y'[x] == 1/y[x]^2 *)
Solve[Equal @@ DSolve[eq, y[x], x][[1, 1]], C[1]]
(* C[1] -> -x + y[x] *)
```

Higher order ODEs contain more constants of integration, so OP shall modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly for both cases

Comment: @Ilya I'm glad I could help. If you try this with more examples, and one doesn't work, let me know and I'll see if I can do something. Cheers!