# DSolve skips restrictions when expressing the solution from the first integral

Tags: differential-equations

I consider the ODE: $$y' =-\frac{y^2+1}{x^2+1},$$
and DSolve

```
DSolve[{y'[x] (x^2 + 1) == -(y[x]^2 + 1)}, y[x], x, 
 Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]]
```

gives the solution $y=y(x)$:

```
{{y[x] -> -Tan[ArcTan[x] - C[1]]}}.
```

But, if I solve the equation by the separable variable method, then I get the general solution in the form
$$\arctan(y(x))+\arctan(x)=C.$$
I can express the solution from this equation in the form of DSolve answer, but I have restriction $   - \pi/2 < C-\arctan(x) <    \pi/2$.
Of course, Reduce gives this resuts:

```
Reduce[ArcTan[y] + ArcTan[x] == c, y, Reals]

1/2 (2 c - Pi) < ArcTan[x] < 1/2 (2 c + Pi) && 
 y == Tan[c - ArcTan[x]]
```

but DSolve does not show it.

What is the reason for this?
Is there any possibility to influence on DSolve?

Comment: Your $C$ and the `DSolve` constant `C[1]` are distinct, the connection being that their difference is a multiple of $\pi$. The `DSolve` answer gives a solution for all `C[1]`, so I'm not sure how you can get `DSolve` to do it your way. This brings out the restriction in terms of the multiple of $\pi$: `First@Solve[Equal @@@ #, {C[1], y[x]}, Reals] & /@ 
 DSolve[{y'[x] (x^2 + 1) == -(y[x]^2 + 1)}, y[x], x]`

Comment: No, my $C$ and `C[1]` from `DSolve` are equal. It follows from $\arctan(y(x))+\arctan(x)=C$: $y(x) = \tan(C-\arctan(x))$. But if we consider the solution  denends on the real argument $x$, this formula is true under the restriction on $x$ which I wrote above. Otherwise, the uniqueness of the solution may not be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Solve},
 Unprotect[Solve];
 Solve[eq_, y[x]] := Solve[eq, y[x], Reals];
 Protect[Solve];
 DSolve[{y'[x] (x^2 + 1) == -(y[x]^2 + 1)}, y[x], x]
 ]
```

[Or](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174467):

```
(* Compare https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/174467 *) 
Trace[
 DSolve[{y'[x] (x^2 + 1) == -(y[x]^2 + 1)}, y[x], x],
 Solve[implicit_, y[x]] :> Return[Solve[implicit, y[x], Reals], Trace],
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

Return this:

```
(*
{{y[x] -> ConditionalExpression[
   -Tan[ArcTan[x] - C[1]], 
   (1/2)*(-Pi + 2*ArcTan[x]) < C[1] < (1/2)*(Pi + 2*ArcTan[x])]}}
*)
```

And an IVP usually gets you proper dependence on parameters,
though IVPs are sometimes harder to solve:

```
DSolve[{y'[x] (x^2 + 1) == -(y[x]^2 + 1), y[0] == c}, y[x], x]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used....

```
(*  {{y[x] -> Tan[ArcTan[c] - ArcTan[x]]}}  *)
```

---

Notes:

1. `DSolve` does not attempt to produce formulas that are 1-1/injective mappings from a parameter domain (say, for the integration constants) to the solution space.
   (The mappings are not always "onto"/surjective either.)
   When the formulas involve transcendental functions,
   you're rather lucky to get formulas straight out of `DSolve`
   that satisfy the desire for "uniqueness,"
   which was a condition added by the OP [in a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253844/dsolve-skips-restrictions-when-expressing-the-solution-from-the-first-integral?noredirect=1#comment634381_253844).
2. `Assumptions` are tricky. Logically, `Assumptions -> P` should be like `Implies[P, Q]` and not `And[P, Q]`.  `Assumptions` sets conditions that may be assumed when useful, but otherwise are not necessary.  That is to say, if you want to impose constraints, using `Assumptions` may or may not have the intended effect.  So the use of `Assumptions -> Element[x, Reals]` in `DSolve` will not force the solution(s) to be real-only.  OTOH, `Solve[..., Reals]` and `Reduce[..., Reals]` make real-only a constraint.  However, in the first two codes, the `Reals` constraint applies only to the final solution step, not the intermediate steps used by `DSolve`.
3. The first code is probably better: If `DSolve[sys, y, x]`, it return a function `y -> Function[{x}, sol]`; the second returns `y[x] -> sol` no matter the form of the `DSolve` call.