# Is there more complete documentation of DSolve with all hacks?

Tags: differential-equations, documentation, undocumented

I know [DSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html?q=DSolve). I know this community and I am able to gather some hacks.

There is this:

```
mid = Trace[
DSolve[{3 y[x] + 2 x y[x]^2 + (2 x + 3 x^2 y[x]) y'[x] == 0, 
  y[1] == 1/2}, y[x], x], Solve[_, y[x]], TraceInternal -> True] //
Flatten // Union
```

and many more, like [coaxing DSolve to produce an implicit solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/137598/coaxing-dsolve-to-produce-an-implicit-solution).  This is to me seemingly necessary to work with [DSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html?q=DSolve). I already found the Wolfram monograph [Working With DSolve: A User's Guide](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveWorkingWithDSolve.html).

For example, how to enter the constants in [wolframcloud.com](https://www.wolframcloud.com)?

I am aware of this [Solve a differential equation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SolveADifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: Please focus your question on as specific problem, with a code example.

Comment: There is also this one [Wolfram Mathematica Tutorial Collection: Differential Equation Solving with DSolve](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Books/8509/)