Output is coming as InverseFunction, how to get the exact solution?
This is the value of $A[z]$, I'm trying to solve the following geodesic equation,
A[z_][t_] = -a z[t]^2;
geodesiceqn = 
 z[t] z''[t] + (1 + z[t] D[A[z][t], z[t]]) z'[t]^2 - Exp[ -2 A[z][t]]
DSolve[geodesiceqn == 0, z[t], t] // Simplify

But the output is coming as InverseFunction as given below.
{{z[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[-((
       E^(a C[1]) Gamma[1/2, a (C[1] + #1^2)] Sqrt[C[1] + #1^2])/(
       2 Sqrt[a (C[1] + #1^2)])) &][t + C[2]]}, {z[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[(
      E^(a C[1]) Gamma[1/2, a (C[1] + #1^2)] Sqrt[C[1] + #1^2])/(
      2 Sqrt[a (C[1] + #1^2)]) &][t + C[2]]}}

What does that mean, and how can we get the exact solution?


Please check the document of InverseFunction by pressing F1 button, it's well-documented. 2. What exact solution are you expecting? The InverseFunction[...] is already an exact solution. 3. Are you expecting something like this?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137598/1871


What does this mean #1?

Just search # in document, it's also well-documented. And, please read the linked answer above carefully.

Thank you for your suggestions.
